# How to extract a json value inside <head> tag inside a <html> reponse in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Here is the response data I received for an Http Request Sampler in Jmeter:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="scripts-not-loaded" dir="ltr"   lang="en">
<head>
<script>
ENV = {"ASSET_HOST":"https://du11hjcvx0uqb.cloudfront.net","active_brand_config_json_url":"https://du11hjcvx0uqb.cloudfront.net/dist/brandable_css/645beea198665f1487136eff16533cde/variables-8391c84da435c9cfceea2b2b3317ff66.json","url_to_what_gets_loaded_inside_the_tinymce_editor_css":["https://du11hjcvx0uqb.cloudfront.net/dist/brandable_css/645beea198665f1487136eff16533cde/variables-8391c84da435c9cfceea2b2b3317ff66.css","https://du11hjcvx0uqb.cloudfront.net/dist/brandable_css/responsive_layout_normal_contrast/bundles/what_gets_loaded_inside_the_tinymce_editor-8bf5101009.css","https://du11hjcvx0uqb.cloudfront.net/dist/brandable_css/no_variables/bundles/lato_extended-a29d3d859f.css"],"url_for_high_contrast_tinymce_editor_css":["https://du11hjcvx0uqb.cloudfront.net/dist/brandable_css/default/variables-high_contrast-8391c84da435c9cfceea2b2b3317ff66.css","https://du11hjcvx0uqb.cloudfront.net/dist/brandable_css/responsive_layout_high_contrast/bundles/what_gets_loaded_inside_the_tinymce_editor-9bad98d5d7.css","https://du11hjcvx0uqb.cloudfront.net/dist/brandable_css/no_variables/bundles/lato_extended-a29d3d859f.css"],"current_user_id":"29487350","current_user_roles":["user","teacher"],"current_user_types":[],"current_user_disabled_inbox":false,"files_domain":"cluster7.canvas-user-content.com","DOMAIN_ROOT_ACCOUNT_ID":"70000000000010","k12":false,"use_responsive_layout":true,"use_rce_enhancements":true,"rce_auto_save":true,"help_link_name":"Help","help_link_icon":"help","use_high_contrast":false,"disable_celebrations":false,"disable_keyboard_shortcuts":false,"LTI_LAUNCH_FRAME_ALLOWANCES":["geolocation","microphone","camera","midi","encrypted-media","autoplay"],"DEEP_LINKING_POST_MESSAGE_ORIGIN":"https://trans.institute.com","DEEP_LINKING_LOGGING":null,"SETTINGS":{"open_registration":true,"collapse_global_nav":false,"show_feedback_link":true},"DIRECT_SHARE_ENABLED":true,"FEATURES":{"cc_in_rce_video_tray":true,"featured_help_links":true,"rce_lti_favorites":true,"rce_pretty_html_editor":true,"rce_better_file_downloading":false,"rce_better_file_previewing":false,"assignment_bulk_edit":true,"responsive_awareness":true,"recent_history":true,"responsive_misc":true,"product_tours":true,"module_dnd":true,"files_dnd":true,"unpublished_courses":true,"usage_rights_discussion_topics":true,"inline_math_everywhere":false,"granular_permissions_manage_users":false,"canvas_for_elementary":false,"canvas_k6_theme":false,"new_math_equation_handling":false},"current_user":{"id":"29487350","display_name":"Aravind ","avatar_image_url":"https://trans.institute.com/images/messages/avatar-50.png","html_url":"https://trans.institute.com/about/29487350","pronouns":null,"avatar_is_fallback":true},"page_view_update_url":"/page_views/c83ff8cf-9ae9-4ede-b16b-fcc4033c5f9e?page_view_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiYzgzZmY4Y2YtOWFlOS00ZWRlLWIxNmItZmNjNDAzM2M1ZjllIiwidSI6NzAwMDAwMjk0ODczNTAsImMiOiIyMDIxLTAzLTA0VDA2OjE5OjI4LjQ2WiJ9.j8GjHgIJBzN1lMUVkKXb5jSQZmbI0nASkWOA7_mUU8I","context_asset_string":"course_2618242","ping_url":"https://trans.institute.com/api/v1/courses/2618242/ping","TIMEZONE":"America/Denver","CONTEXT_TIMEZONE":"America/Denver","LOCALE":"en","BIGEASY_LOCALE":"en_US","FULLCALENDAR_LOCALE":"en","MOMENT_LOCALE":"en","rce_auto_save_max_age_ms":86400000,"HOMEROOM_COURSE":false,"INCOMPLETE_REGISTRATION":null,"USER_EMAIL":"a4aravind@gmail.com","CONFIRMED":true,"current_user_created_at":1614330021,"badge_counts":{"submissions":0},"NEW_USER_TUTORIALS":{"is_enabled":true},"COURSE":{"id":"2618242","pages_url":"https://trans.institute.com/courses/2618242/pages","front_page_title":null,"default_view":"modules","is_student":false,"is_instructor":true},"course_id":"2618242","CONTEXT_URL_ROOT":"/courses/2618242","DUPLICATE_ENABLED":true,"FILES_CONTEXTS":[{"asset_string":"course_2618242"}],"MODULE_FILE_DETAILS":{},"MODULE_FILE_PERMISSIONS":{"usage_rights_required":false,"manage_files_edit":true},"MODULE_TRAY_TOOLS":{"module_index_menu":[{"id":"69910","title":"Commons Favorites","base_url":"https://trans.institute.com/courses/2618242/external_tools/69910?launch_type=module_index_menu","icon_url":"https://lor.instructure.com/img/icon_commons.png","canvas_icon_class":"icon-commons"}],"module_group_menu":[{"id":"69910","title":"Commons Favorites","base_url":"https://trans.institute.com/courses/2618242/external_tools/69910?launch_type=module_group_menu","icon_url":"https://lor.instructure.com/img/icon_commons.png","canvas_icon_class":"icon-commons"}]},"DEFAULT_POST_TO_SIS":false,"new_quizzes_modules_support":false,"CONTEXT_MODULE_ASSIGNMENT_INFO_URL":"/courses/2618242/modules/items/assignment_info","COLLAPSED_MODULES":[],"CAN_MANAGE_MODULES":true,"IS_STUDENT":false,"COURSE_ID":"2618242","NO_MODULE_PROGRESSIONS":false,"notices":[],"active_context_tab":"home"};
</script>
```

I want to extract the value of 'course_id' ie; "2618242" from the above  response. Please help out with a solution, since using JSON Path Extractor or Reg Exp Extractor didn't work out for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON Path Extractor only when response is JSON, in your case the JSON is "hidden" in HTML tags, moreover you need partial attribute value so it makes sense to consider using Regular Expression Extractor

Suggested regular expression:

```
course_(\d+)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [Perl | Regex Cheat Sheet](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-regex-cheat-sheet/)